# Fastlane Scan: How to add '--screenshots' (xcpretty flag)?

Tags: testing, screenshot, xcodebuild, fastlane

I need to add my screenshots to html-report after **Fastlane Scan** runs the tests, but here's the problem:  `--screenshots` is **xcpretty**'s flag, not **xcodebuild**'s.

**Scan** has no such parameter, like `xcpretty_args` in **Snapshot**. So now I'm forced to run my tests without Scan but with next script:

```
set -o pipefail && env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild -workspace ./MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme myScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7 Plus,OS=10.3.1' -derivedDataPath 'build'
-only-testing:myTarget/myTestSuite01 test-without-building| xcpretty -r html --screenshots -r junit
```

So, is it possible to do it any way with Scan?

Comment: I think solution could appear here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12316